# Qt pro file conditional libs

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, conditional-compilation

I am trying to setup a pro file where I want it to only include a specific library if a variable is defined. I already have this variable passed into qmake via the command line by appending DEFINES+=VARIABLE_NAME.

I can use VARIABLE_NAME to conditionally compile parts of my code but can I have a condition to detect VARIABLE_NAME in the pro file and only include a library if it exists?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that:

```
DEFINES += USELIB

contains(DEFINES, USELIB) {
  LIBS += SOMELIB
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this will do the job.